# Excel - Can not compare two spreadsheets

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have gone through V-look-up guides online but I can not find one that explains what I am looking for. I am trying to avoid manual checking.

**What I have:**

Two sheets, *Sheet 1* and *Sheet 2*. Both sheets have the same column names (A1:G1) with multiple rows.

Sheet 1 contains my spreadsheet where I update daily. Sheet 2 is the same spreadsheet that is imported from a application (but has hourly updates). Data can change in each row (for some columns) along with additional added/deleted rows. The data is text, dates and numbers (mixture of both too).

I want to run a formula to highlight the changes on sheet 1 (grabbing the updates from sheet 2. Once I find out the formula works correctly, I would like to know how to replace the Sheet 2 updates onto my spreadsheet (Sheet 1).

I am looking for a formula outside of creating a macro (worst case scenario).

Currently I have the following vlook up formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,sheet2!$A:$A,1,FALSE)
```

When I run this in another column (lets say in H1 in *Sheet 1*), it will display "N/A" if that column (A1) *in Sheet 2* is not the same. If it is the same, it will write out the column name.

When I use the following formula highlighting all the cells in *Sheet 1*, I get a values error:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1:G33,Sheet2!$A:$G,1,FALSE)
```

How could I apply that formula to the whole spreadsheet (I guess it would apply to both sheets) and have it highlight records in my spreadsheet (Sheet1). Could it also highlight rows that are missing or added?

The data in Column 1 and 2 would never change (they are ticket numbers). Only change that can apply is if ticket is closed, so when I import the updated spreadsheet that row isn't there anymore. If you think there might be a better way to tackle this down, I would like to hear.

Please let me know if I am not clear.

Here are some example screenshots:

[image]

Just in case, the formula for the totals are (adjusting the columns for each):

```
=SUBTOTAL(3,INDEX(C:C,2):INDEX(C:C,ROW()-1))
```

Sheet 2 is setup very similar. When I import it into excel, the columns are the exact same as Sheet 1, the only difference can be more/less rows (along with the updates for each row).

Comment: Not sure what guides you read but you can't do `=VLOOKUP(A1:G33`. What you want to do is not possible without vba.

Comment: If I read what you want correctly, you'll need to set up a sort of check table that compares current values in Sheet1 with current values in Sheet2, and then use some conditional formatting to highlight the differences then adjust  `Sheet1` accordingly, probably through a small macro. It may help us too, if you can provide screenshots of the data (or samples of the data).

Comment: Yes, you understood it perfectly. I will go ahead and include a few screenshots in a couple minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formatting.
[image]

Comment: I get the following error:

"This type of reference cannt be used in a conditional Formatting Formula. Change the reference to a single cell, or use the reference with a worksheet function, such as =SUM(A1:E5)"